# Axis while deleting a column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

axis refers to the dimension of the array, in the case of pd.DataFrames axis=0 is the dimension that points downwards (column) and axis=1 the one that points to the right(row)

However, while dropping a column we are supposed to write the code as

```
df = df.drop("BuildingArea", axis = 1)
```

instead of

```
df = df.drop("BuildingArea", axis = 0)
```

Why is that so ? This is counter-intuitive.